# cardinality vertex cover with maximum matching in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, vertex-cover

Is the problem of cardinality vertex cover solvable using the maximum matching in polynomial time? 
What is the coefficient of approximation?
please help me

Comment: Have you tried looking for this online? Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes but I could not understand the whole thing. Can you introduce a site to better understand the concept?